# multi-line commands in Julia

Tags: shell, julia

You can run commands in Julia using the following syntax:

```
run(`echo 123`)
```

How can I easily run a long command with multiple arguments? It is convenient to split it up over multiple lines for readability purposes. Can I do this in Julia?

Comment: Wouldn't it have taken like half the time of asking to just try it out in the console?

Comment: I've tried it the other way: constructed a whole string which I then put into backticks. Now I had to worry about escaping. Basically, I didn't know the right way of doing this and it's not documented in the official manual.

Comment: fair enough :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Julia automatically continues parsing in the next line if the current expression is incomplete, e.g.,

```
julia> 1 +
       2
3
```

Therefore, you can simply do

```
julia> run(`
           echo 
           123
           345
           678
       `)
123 345 678
```

Answer (score 4):

Be sure not to leave a complete command in the first line.

```
julia> 1
       +2
2
```

This is a mistake that I made when writing a long expression in a .jl file.

Comment: This makes you think that an explicit line-continuation would be good. Like `\` in sh.